# QPushButton.clicked.connect doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, connection, qt5, pyside2, qpushbutton

I am trying to decouple entirely my GUI from my controller class, and for some reason I can't seem to manage to connect my buttons from outside of my GUI class itself.

Here's a small example of what I mean :

```py
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets


class Gui(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Gui, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Do stuff")
        layout.addWidget(self.button)


class Controller(object):
    def do_stuff(self):
        print("something")


def startup(parent):
    ctrl = Controller()
    gui = Gui(parent)
    gui.button.clicked.connect(ctrl.do_stuff)
    return gui


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    gui = startup(dialog)
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would expect this code, when run, to display a GUI with one push button (which it does), and when pressing the push button, I'd expect the word "something" to get printed. However this doesn't seem to be the case.
I might just be too tired, but I can't find the solution.

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `ctrl` gets garbage collected, and its `do_stuff` along with it. Just `return ctrl, gui` and `ctrl, gui = startup(dialog)`. The persistence of `ctrl` is of utmost importance: that's your *controller*, you cannot ignore it that easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
ctrl = None
gui = None
def startup(parent):
    global ctrl
    global gui
    ctrl = Controller()
    gui = Gui(parent)
    gui.button.clicked.connect(ctrl.do_stuff)
    return gui
```

try this, and it does work. when the variable is in the function, it will be destroyed before the function is finished. the global variable is not a good coding style but is a simple way to figure out your confusion.

Comment: Even assuming it might *actually* help to "figure out the confusion", it would create even more with the introduction of global without proper context and without enough awareness. Globals are not automatically "evil", but they should be always used carefully (especially when suggesting them).

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said it is not a good coding style. In this short case, it may easily help the asker realize there is a difference between variable out of function and in function.

Comment: With all due respect, if it's not good coding style, you shall not suggest it, unless you then provide the *actually* good one and point out *why* the other isn't, clarifying that it shouldn't be done and you did it only for explanation purposes. Right now your answer puts that too lightly, something like "you shouldn't do it, but it works, so you can do it". Which would be fine for an experienced programmer that would understand the implications. Not for a beginner that wouldn't be able to discriminate the serious consequences that that practice could create.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however I don't quite understand why it would need to be global, considering that it is being returned and stored in a variable. In particular, if it was the case, I wouldn't be able to do `gui.show()` in the main statement and still have the gui show up.
It does sound like converting that startup function into an object that keeps a reference to it would work, that said I'd like to understand how I am being mistaken here, regarding my current approach.

Comment: Nevermind, I just didn't see @musicamante 's comment on my post, which totally makes sense, thanks!

Comment: let's back to your function startup, you defined two variables, one is ctrl, and another is gui. when the function is finished. the ctrl and gui will be deleted. if you want to use the ctrl's own function do_stuff, you should make the variable ctrl always alive, a global variable is always alive, the better way is to define a new class for your variable dialog whose parent object is QtWidgets.QDialog(). and define all your needed variables in the new class __init__ function.